# Proof that q is a semidefinite quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I've been stuck on a question in my linear algebra course for quite some time:

Let V be a finite dimensional vector space over $R$ and $q:V \to R$ a quadratic form.
Prove that if $$L=\{v|q(v)\ge0\}$$ is a subspace of $V$, then q is semidefinite. Not sure how to start, I'd appreciate a hint.

Comment: Did you intend for the domain of $q$ to be $V$ instead of $R$?

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is my first answer on this site. I hope I'm not writing a disaster.

Suppose that $L = \{v|q(v) \geq 0\}$ is a proper subspace of $V$, so $V = L \bigoplus U$, where $U$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $U \cap L = \{ 0 \}$(this is important) and $U + L = V$. Now if $v \in U-\{ 0 \}$ then how $q(v)$ could be?
If $q(v) \geq 0$ then $v \in L \cap U = \{ 0 \}$, absurd. So if $v \in U$ then $q(v) < 0$. 
Let $w = v + u \in V$ where $v \in L$ and $u \in U$, what can you say about $q(u + v)$?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well If $q(v) \geq 0$ then $v \in U \cap L = \{ 0 \}$ which is a contradiction. So $q(v) < 0$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Of course you have to analyze when $w = v + u$ where $u \in U$ and $v \in V$, but the reasoning is pretty much the same. I didn't end the sentence because I thought it was clear or deductible as hint.

Comment: So you are then showing the claim is *false*, right? Ok. Perhaps it could conditioned that $\;L\;$ is a *proper* subspace to avoid trivial cases. Nice.+1

Answer (score 2):

The assertion is plainly wrong. Take the form $q(v)=v_1^2$ on the two-dimensional space $V$ with coordinates $(v_1,v_2)$; then $L=V$ is a subspace of $V$, but the form is not definite.

Now the amended statement (the form is semidefinite) is true. Proof: If $q\equiv 0$ on $L$, then $q$ is clearly negative semidefinite. If this is not the case, then let $v_0\in L$ be a point such that $q(v_0)>0$. Since $q$ is continuous, there exists a ball $B$ with center $v_0$ on which $q>0$. Hence $B\subset L$, and we conclude that $L$ is the entire space $V$; i.e., $q$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: No way. Take $v=(0,1)\ne0$. Then $q(v)=0^2=0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I need to prove that q is semidefinite

Comment: I think that's whats been confusing me so long.

Comment: Okay, then you can do it yorself, or do you still need help?

Comment: Could you give me a direction to work with? Im having trouble with this subject.

Comment: @Vladimir Your added explanation deviates a lot from plain linear algebra and gets into topology. Is this necessary?

Comment: @DonAntonio This is sufficient. Maybe it is good sport to try and prove this with ruler and compasses alone, but my opinion is one should comprehend the world in its entirety))

Comment: @Vladimir That may be nice in some respect yet it won't help *at all* to a linear algebra student, say. Banach, Hilbert spaces, topological spaces or groups, etc. are usually advanced undergraduate stuff. That's why I asked "does this **has to be done** that way"? Also, look the other answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ok, you have made a point. What if we say: take the plane orthogonal to $L$ at $v_0$. Then, being continuous, $q(v)>0$ on that plane near $v_0$, and hence some points of this plane other than $v_0$ lie in $L$ "--- which is a contradiction. Is this good enough for linear algebra students?

Comment: @Vladimir Not really, I think. Whenever you use "continuity" here you're entering the realm of topology. This doesn't exist in basic linear algebra (except, of course, for examples of linear spaces of all continuous functions, etc.)

Comment: @DonAntonio Ok, I agree. Forbidden knowledge, er? Then maybe linear algebra students should stick with Ker's answer.

Comment: @VladimirI don't think it is about "forbidden language" but about "knowledge level of basic linear algebra", which is what this question most problaby requires. I can solve some (im)proper Riemann integrals by means of complex integration, but it would most probably be way above the level someone in first or second year needs. That's all.